# start_with not working for backslash in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the following string -

```
abcdefgh;
lmnopqrst;
```

On doing a `string = string.split(";")`, I get -

```
["abcdefgh", "\nlmnopqrst"]
```

Now when I do -

```
string[1].start_with?("\\")
```

The function returns false. Whereas if I do 
`string[0].start_with?("a")`
The function return true.

I am new to ruby and just can't understand this behavior. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because "\n" actually *does not start with a backslash* . It is the line feed character and is considered to be a single character and for that reason it is only presented having the escape character `\` in front of it.

So:

```
string[1].start_with?("\n")
```

Will return true.

You already tried to search with `string[1].start_with?("\\")` so you seem to realize you need to escape the backslash character by using `\\`.

If your input string would look like this:

```
\abcdefgh;
lmnopqrst;
```

Then after `.split(';')` your resulting array would look like this:

```
["\\abcdefgh;", "\nlmnopqrst"]
```

Now `string[0].start_with?("\\")` would return `true` because the first string actually starts with a single backslash, which was presented with the escape character in the console.

Answer (score 3):

I dont know, but`String[1][0]` (first character from string) returns `"\n"` so maybe use this

```
string[1].start_with?("\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
'\nhello world'.start_with?("\\") # return true
"\nhello world".start_with?("\\") # return false
```

because `'\n'` is two chars( `\` and `n`), but `"\n"` is one char(`new line char`).

Answer (score 0):

The first character there is not `"\"` - it's `"\n"` in the first example, and `"\\"` in the second.  `"\n"` and `"\\"` are effectively single characters in this context, even though they look like two characters.

`"\n"` != `"\\"`, and so `start_with?` responds false.